# Search texts only in lines within certain number of character range

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am newbie and need a regex for a translation project which helps to search certain text only in lines contains min 1 and max 20 characters. I searched the internet and could not find a satisfactory result. Could you help me? Thank you

For Example:

```
1 testbtblal balbl al2845 tetete gsgsgs tetet
2 testblablablablal gsgsg gsgs gsgsg gsg
3 blabltetst alets jff            <----- 
4 125testblabal14test ablets blbla
5 test2584blaalj                  <----- Less than 20 characters also contains "bla" text
7 4rblatesbaltest845 testblabla test
8 blabalbal878testbaltesbla blabla test            
9 2584blaal jstba lest            <------
10 blablatest5 45blabla ffftest
```

There are 10 lines and each one contains "bla" text. But I need to find and replace only bla word in lines less than 20 characters.

Comment: It's part of the what I wanted. But I need to search some text in this range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: There is no my answer in this reference post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this simple expression,

```
^.{21,}$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|bla
```

and a replacement of,

```
SOME_NEW_STRING
```

might solve the problem. Here, we'd simply find any string longer than 20 chars, then we'd SKIP FAIL, then we'd simply replace `bla` with anything else that is desired.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HuPOdQ/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/HuPOdQ/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---